# Rails no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a private method that does some counting based on some database data as follows.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    before_action :moderation_count

    private

    def moderation_count
      @count = '';
      @count[:venues_pending] = Venue.where(:is_approved => 0).count.to_i
      @count[:venues_rejected] = Venue.where(:is_approved => 2).count.to_i
      @count[:venue_photos_pending] = VenuePhoto.where(:is_approved => 0).count.to_i
      @count[:venue_photos_rejected] = VenuePhoto.where(:is_approved => 2).count.to_i
      @count[:venue_reviews_pending] = VenueReview.where(:is_approved => 0).count.to_i
      @count[:venue_reviews_rejected] = VenueReview.where(:is_approved => 2).count.to_i
    end
end
```

**Error:**

> no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have set `@count` as an empty `String` with

```
@count = '';
```

so when you do `@count[:venues_pending]`, `Ruby` tries to convert the *Symbol* `:venues_pending`  to an *Integer* to access a particular index of the String `@count`.
This is resulting in the error as `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`

As you are planning to use the instance variable `@count` as a `Hash`, you should instantiate it as a Hash rather than an empty String.

Use `@count = {};` or `@count = Hash.new;`

Comment: thanks a lot. I had sent a message to you on fb before to connect and i find u here as well :D