# TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a pretty basic question.

I tried the solution posted [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370707/rails-no-implicit-conversion-of-symbol-into-integer)

However it is not working for me.

My code is:

```
#Logic for connecting to end point and getting the response is above this line...

puts res.body
Rails.logger.debug "Response from endpoint: #{res.body}"

# Once a successful response is received, update the corresponding service table.

content = Hash.new
Rails.logger.debug "Content initial value: #{content}"

content = res.body
Rails.logger.debug "Content loaded value: #{content}"

if content[:result].length != 0
  if content[:result][:hotel][:@type] == "LodgingReservation"

#More logic below this line . . .
```

The format of the response i.e. "res.body" is json and it looks like this

```
{"message": "OK", "code": 200, "id": "de97c01a-b206-11e5-8976-0a5d4c2d1469", "result": {"hotel": {"reservationFor": {"telephone": "+123456", "@type": "LodgingBusiness", "x-days": "6"}, "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/ReservationConfirmed", "broker": {"@type": "Organization", "name": "xyz"}, "checkoutTime": "2014-04-06T12:00:00", "reservationId": "426396323", "checkinTime": "2014-03-31T15:00:00", "@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "LodgingReservation"}}}
```

When I try to run the code it gives the "TypeError:" at this line -- `if content[:result].length != 0`

The following is output from the debugger:

```
Content initial value: {}

Content loaded value: {"message": "OK", "code": 200, "id": "de97c01a-b206-11e5-8976-0a5d4c2d1469", "result": {"hotel": {"reservationFor": {"telephone": "+123456", "@type": "LodgingBusiness", "x-days": "6"}, "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/ReservationConfirmed", "broker": {"@type": "Organization", "name": "xyz"}, "checkoutTime": "2014-04-06T12:00:00", "reservationId": "426396323", "checkinTime": "2014-03-31T15:00:00", "@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "LodgingReservation"}}}
```

As you can see from the output "content" is not a hash. I'm trying to figure out why?

When I run this code line by line in the **rails console** *it is working*.

```
>> c = Hash.new
=> {}
>> c = {"message": "OK", "code": 200, "id": "de97c01a-b206-11e5-8976-0a5d4c2d1469", "result": {"hotel": {"reservationFor": {"telephone": "+123456", "@type": "LodgingBusiness", "x-days": "6"}, "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/ReservationConfirmed", "broker": {"@type": "Organization", "name": "xyz"}, "checkoutTime": "2014-04-06T12:00:00", "reservationId": "426396323", "checkinTime": "2014-03-31T15:00:00", "@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "LodgingReservation"}}}
=> {:message=>"OK", :code=>200, :id=>"3048f3f4-b205-11e5-849c-0a5d4c2d1469", :result=>{:hotel=>{:reservationFor=>{:telephone=>"+123456", :@type=>"LodgingBusiness", :"x-days"=>"6", :reservationStatus=>"http://schema.org/ReservationConfirmed", :broker=>{:@type=>"Organization", :name=>"xyz"}, :checkoutTime=>"2014-04-06T12:00:00", :reservationId=>"426396323", :checkinTime=>"2014-03-31T15:00:00", :@context=>"http://schema.org", :@type=>"LodgingReservation"}}}
>> c[:result].length
=> 1
>> c[:result].length !=0
=> true
>> c[:result][:hotel][:@type]
=> "LodgingReservation"
>> c[:result][:hotel][:@type] == "LodgingReservation"
=> true
```

As you can it is working perfectly from the rails console. Any ideas on how I can fix this strange issue?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys are being converted to strings so try

```
content["result"].length
```

Comment: Yes, your solved the problem for the line of code                                           --> if content[:result].length != 0.                                                                  But when I applied your solution to the next line of code                                      -->if content[:result][:hotel][:@type] == "LodgingReservation" it is giving the following error               --->NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass. The changed code is ---> if content["result"]["hotel"]["@type"] == "LodgingReservation"

Comment: Strictly speaking, you should accept my answer and post a new question for the new error. You'll need to do some debugging - what does content["result"]["hotel"] return? Are you sure you saved your new code, have no typos in it? I ran content["result"]["hotel]["@type"] in the console and it returned "LodgingReservation".